# Nonce Error when checking out with Square on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, square, nonce

I am attempting to checkout in my flutter app. I can create my card and retrieve card details with my key and location id. But, after I add the card to my profile,  I attempt to checkout with the card I get the nonce:

At this point I get the "CNOF:xxxxxx"

Then when using that nonce, I get this error:

> Card nonce already used with a different idempotency key; please
> request new nonce.

Then after re-adding the card or trying to use the same card, I get the actual nonce "ccof:xxxx: error:

> customer_id must be present when supplying customer payment on file in
> the source_id

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Thanks.

Comment: I have same issue, any progress.

Comment: @MikeFlynn you have get the nonce. Double check the info that is coming back